# Displaying Unprintable Characers in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, character, ascii, rendering

I'm trying to create a game with ASCII art in Pygame 2.7.  If I go to the Idle console and simply type:

```
for i in range(255):
    print str(i) + ' - ' + str(chr(i))
```

I get nearly 255 distinct characters.  However, if I try a similar stunt in Pygame:

```
import pygame, os, string, sys
from pygame.locals import * 
pygame.init()

class Prog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = 'Text'
        self.screen_size = (800, 600)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.screen_size)
        self.bg_color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.text_color = (0,0,0)
        self.text_font = 'Times New Roman'
        self.text_size = 20
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(self.text_font, self.text_size)

    def draw_text(self, text, x, y):
        textobj = self.font.render(text, 1, self.text_color)
        textrect = textobj.get_rect()
        textrect.center = (x,y)
        self.screen.blit(textobj, textrect)
    def main(self):
        rec = self.screen.get_rect()
        done = False
        while not done:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    done = True

            self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
            x = 20
            y = 100
            n = 1
            for i in range(1, 255):
                self.draw_text(chr(i), x, y)
                x += 20
                n += 1
                if n > 25:
                    n = 1
                    x = 20
                    y += 30
            pygame.display.flip()
```

Most of it is just empty boxes.  Why the discrepancy?  I've tried changing fonts, even using the one that Idle uses; I've tried parsing it as unicode; nothing seems to work.  It wouldn't bother me so much if not for the fact that, as I said, it prints in Idle just fine, and some of the characters I can't get are present in other ASCII games I play, so it must somehow be renderable.

Can anyone advise? I'm a self/google-taught amateur, and would honestly prefer not to have to download extra modules if at all avoidable.  If nothing else, I'll settle for an explanation of my computer's apparent double-standard on this issue.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main issue is that Pygame and Idle are using different default encodings to interpret your strings. Strings in Python 2 are tough to understand, so bear with me a little. Also, correct me if I'm mistaken, but I'm assuming you're using Python 2, which handles strings much differently than Python 3.

Strings in Python 2 are just series of bytes. Bytes in Python 2 can be expressed as bytes literals by creating a `bytes` object or prepending a string with `b`.

```
'a' == b'a' == bytes(a)
>>>True
```

`chr(i)` "Returns a string of one character whose ASCII code is the integer i." ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr)) If a string is a series of bytes, `chr` returns bytes. Let's look at what `chr` returns if we call it in the Python 2 interpreter:

```
chr(97)
>>>'a'
chr(120)
>>>'x'
```

The reason those letters show up in the interpreter output is that Python 2's default encoding is ASCII, so when it sees a byte value that corresponds to a symbol on the ASCII chart, it replaces the byte with that symbol. ASCII is limited to symbols corresponding to values 0 through 127. [This chart](http://www.asciitable.com/) shows what symbol each value corresponds to. 97 is 'a' and 120 is 'x'.

You'll notice that 0-31 and 127 are "control characters" that don't represent symbols, but communicate things to the machine reading the text. For example, in the C language, the end of a string is denoted by the null character, which is codepoint 0 in ASCII.

`chr` accepts an argument from 0 through 255. What happens if we pass an integer to `chr` that represents a control character in ASCII? What if we pass it an integer greater than 127?

```
chr(4)
>>>'\x04'
chr(163)
>>>'\xa3'
```

`\x` in a string in Python tells the interpreter that the next two characters represent a [hexadecimal](https://www.mathsisfun.com/hexadecimals.html) value. When the byte value doesn't have a corresponding symbol in ASCII, the interpreter just shows us the byte value as a hexadecimal number. Behind the scenes, `'a'` is just `'\x61'`, but the interpreter uses ASCII to show us what '\x61' represents.

There are lots of encodings besides ASCII. UTF-8 is a very common one you've probably heard of. Like ASCII, it relates numerical values to symbols. [This chart](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) shows the first 256 codepoints in UTF-8. They correspond exactly to what is being output by your pygame code:

[image: pygame output]

So you're passing bytes to the `drawtext` function, and it's using UTF-8 to interpret those bytes as symbols. When it gets a value that corresponds to a control character, it simply outputs the square instead.

The reason Idle shows you different symbols is because it uses a different default encoding than Pygame. Without knowing what symbols it outputs, I can't say which encoding it is. ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252 are two other very common encodings. You can check which encoding Idle is using by going to Preferences > General and looking at the "Default Source Encoding" option.

So what do you do about it? If you truly want to limit yourself to ASCII symbols, you can use the `string` module, which contains useful lists of characters. You can get all non-whitespace ASCII characters with the following code:

```
import string
ascii_characters = string.digits + string.letters + string.punctuation
print ascii_characters
```

If you want to use more than just those characters, Pygame will never be able to render UTF-8's control characters. Here are 2 options I see.

1. Pass a unicode string containing the character you want. This option requires you to declare a different default encoding on the first line of your file using a magic comment:

   `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
   `...`
   `self.drawtext(u"€", x, y)`
2. Pass a unicode string containing the unicode designation for the symbol you want. This does not require the magic comment from option 1.

   `self.draw_text(u'\u20ac', x, y)`

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I got more out of your post than weeks of staring at the documentation. :)  (I think the python docs assume a baseline of programming knowledge that is just slightly beyond what I currently have, but I'm getting there!)

Comment: You're very welcome! I started out as a self-taught programmer using pygame, so I'm very happy to help. It's a great question, too. I learned a lot from reading about how strings work in Python. Best of luck with the game!

By the way, if what I wrote answered your question, would you mind accepting it as the answer? It's the way Stack Exchange sites encourage you to give feedback on answers. [answer etiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19448/etiquette-for-selecting-answers). Thanks!